# 33 second load time - Optimized website, good host. This is KILLING ME....

Tags: performance, page-load-time

So im crazy frustrated right now... I have applied all the speed-optimizing techniques I know and the site still takes 20+ seconds to load. The site even has ratings above 80 on pagespeed insights and gtmetrix. here is the site sthlmhotel.se and also ettsmart.se. Both are hosted on a decent hosting plan so I don't think thats the problem. there seems to be a long time-to-first-byte. But I dont really know what that means.

I will be so grateful for any help at all on this!

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apflq.jpg)

Comment: 522 connection timeout. Where are you keeping css?

Comment: /sthlmhotel.se/public_html/css/style.css